# How to make a Black Jack game out of a predefinded deck class

Tags: java, arrays, class, bag

So in class we had to do the ArrayBag class, which im sure all of you know about. If not its all over the internet. Anyway our project is to turn that into a black Jack game. I however have no idea how to do this. I would want to make a card class a deck class then the black jack class. However once again i dont know how i could implement that into the Array bag class. Someone help! Ill add the codes for what i have so far.

Array bag

```
package bag;

//I will will keep T because its the norm, but i really don't want to.
public class ArrayBag <T> implements BagInterface<T>{

private final T [] bag; // our generic array
private static final int DefualtItemCapacity = 52; // our default capacity of items...Make DEFAULT all caps because all the i's made it look ugly
private int numberOfItems ;


 public ArrayBag (int itemCapacity){
     numberOfItems = 0 ; // set numberOfItems to empty 0 
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // java i know what im doing, #Suppressed !
     T[] tempBag = (T[]) new Object [itemCapacity];
     bag= tempBag;
 }// end constructor  

 public ArrayBag() {
     this(DefualtItemCapacity);
 } // if nothing, call DefualtItemCapacity, dont have to check for null if we overload the method 

 // thank you eclipse, for creating the methods from the interface :)
 @Override
 public int getCurrentSize() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return numberOfItems;
 }// end current size

 @Override
 public boolean isFull() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return numberOfItems==bag.length; // return numberOfItems as full 
 }// end full

 @Override
 public boolean isEmpty() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return numberOfItems==0;// return numberOfItems as empty  
 }// end empty

 @Override
 public boolean add(T newItem) {
     boolean result = true ;
     if(isFull()){ // bag is full , return false
         result = false ;
     } else { // bag is not full add new item 
         bag[numberOfItems]= newItem ;
         numberOfItems++;
     }
     return result;
 }// end bool add

 @Override
 public T remove() {
     T temp = bag[numberOfItems-1]; // bag numberOfItems is now one less
     bag[numberOfItems-1]=null ; // then we have to set that spot to null 
             numberOfItems--; // then make sure numberOfItems is one less aswell

     return temp;
 }// end T remove

 @Override
 public boolean remove(T anItem) {
     boolean result = true ;
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
       if(bag[numberOfItems]== anItem ) {
             bag[numberOfItems] = null ;
/* items[numItems-1] = null;*/ // this might shift it left 
             numberOfItems--;
             result = true;
       }else {
             result = false ;   // item not found
       }

     }
     return result;
 }// end bool remove

 @Override
 public void clear() {
     while(!isEmpty()){ // while the bag is not empty we can remove stuff.
         remove();
     }

 }// end clear

 @Override
 public T grab() {
    int i;
    while (numberOfItems != 0){ // while numberOfItems is not empty
    i = (int)(Math.random( ) * numberOfItems) + 1; // i is a random value  
    return bag[i]; // return random item from bag
    }
    return null ; // is empty , return null
 } // end grab


 @Override
 public int getFrequencyOf(T anItem) { // count how many items are the same
     int count=0 ; // count how many are the same
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
         if(bag[i]==anItem){ // if current item = an item add to the count value
             count++;
         }
     }
     return count;
 }// end Frequency

 @Override
 public boolean contains(T anItem) {
    while(anItem != null){
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
         if (anItem.equals(bag[i])){ //bag contains the specified item, use .equals because java is dumb and == gives an error.
             return true;
             }
     }
    }return false; // bag doesnt contain item

 }// end contains

 @Override
 public T[] toArray() { // creates and returns an array containing all of the items
     T[] result = (T[]) new Object [numberOfItems]; 
     for(int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
         result[i]=bag[i];
     }
     return result;
 } // end toArray
} // end class
```

CardClass

```
package bag;

public class Card {
private String cardSuit ; 
private int card ; 

 Card(String suit, int card ){
    this.cardSuit = cardSuit ; 
    this.card = card ;
}
 public String toString(){ // Mr.Englend, i overloaded the toString :'(
     String CardNumber = null; 

         switch (this.card){ 
         case 1: 
             CardNumber = "Ace" ; 
             break;
         case 2: 
             CardNumber = "Two" ; 
             break;
         case 3: 
             CardNumber = "Three" ; 
             break; 
         case 4: 
             CardNumber = "Four" ; 
             break; 
         case 5: 
             CardNumber = "Five" ; 
             break; 
         case 6: 
             CardNumber = "Six" ; 
             break; 
         case 7: 
             CardNumber = "Seven" ;  
             break; 
         case 8: 
             CardNumber = "Eight" ;  
             break; 
         case 9: 
             CardNumber = "Nine" ; 
             break; 
         case 10 :
             CardNumber = "Ten" ; 
             break ; 
         case 11: 
             CardNumber = "Jack" ;
         case 12: 
             CardNumber = "Queen" ;
        case 13:
            CardNumber = "King" ;
            break; 
        case 14:
            CardNumber = "Ace" ;
            break; 
        default: 
            CardNumber = "ERROR" ;
            break; 
            }

            return CardNumber + "Of " +cardSuit.toString() ; 
 }
}
```

BlackJack Class

```
   package bag;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJack {
private static  ArrayBag Deck = new ArrayBag();
private Card[] mycard ; 
//private static  Card Card = new Card();


 public static void main(String[] args) {
      boolean play = true ;
      boolean winner = false ; // bool win
      int money = 100 ;  // amount of money
      int bet = 0 ;  // amount user bets
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Deck.add(3);
      System.out.println(Deck.isEmpty());
      System.out.println(Deck.contains(3));
      System.out.println(Deck.toArray());

      }// end main

 void shuffle(){
     for(int i = 1; i <= 52 ; i++){
         System.out.println(Deck.add(i));
     }

 }

      void drawCard(){
          while(!Deck.isEmpty()){ 

          } // end while not empty

      } // draw card

    }// end class
```

Comment: Around your 11th and 12th case statements, you forget to put a `break` there.

Comment: Question needs to be more specific and less "do my homework"

Comment: Sorry i didnt mean it like that. I ment how do i putt the Card class into the ArrayBag class, since Array bag will be my Deck. I was kinda just looking for a push in the right direction or an idea on what i could do. Not do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search can be your best friend:
http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes4/c5/ex-5-5-answer.html

Comment: Yeah i saw this but, it doesnt use the ArrayBag class i have too. So its totally different